# Can we use android phones as google home device

Tags: actions-on-google

After creating private API.AI agent, I can test it using the simulator. But is it possible to test it in Android phones ?

Answer (score 1):

Not yet. But you can use the "Agent Page" under Integration in API.AI to give you a web view you can use from the phone.  Easy to share too!

Answer (score 0):

As given in https://docs.api.ai/docs/sdks API.AI has provided support for many platforms and using it we can access our private agent.
i.e as given in https://github.com/api-ai/api-ai-android-sdk#getting_started , I created android app by providing access_token detail of my agent and now I can pass the request via my android phone; similarly i used node.js and can make request to my API.AI agent from Linux PC

Answer (score 0):

You can do this now that Google has pushed the Assistant to the Google Pixel, Nexus 6p, and Nexus 5x. No other phone currently can use the assistant.

**Edit 4/17/17**: Upon successfully deploying my own agent I was expecting to be able to use it on my phone after being able to test and preview it on my phone. However it was not working so I contacted their support and got the following answer:

> Sorry for the inconvenience, but Actions on Google are not currently
>   supported on any device other than Google home. The functionality you
>   are referring to was the result of a bug that allowed access across
>   multiple devices to a subset of users, that bug was patched and that
>   is why you lost the functionality. Google is planning to make Actions
>   on Google available across multiple devices, but as per policy, we
>   don't comment on timelines for releases in support.